# more than 1 form with onsubmit using different function

Tags: javascript, html, validation, onsubmit

I have 2 forms, one for email and one for phonenumber, I created 2 functions inside a  to Validate the email and PhoneNumber, but when I submit its just uses the Function associated to the First Form.

I can actually swap between First and Second form and always will only run the one what comes first in the code, but the other will never run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validatePhone()
{
var y=document.forms["MyPhone"]["PhoneN"].value;
var Pholen=y.length
if (Pholen < 10)
  {
  alert("Number must be at last 10 Chars");
  return false;
  }
}

function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["MyMail"]["mailN"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>

<form name='MyPhone' onsubmit="return validatePhone()" method="post">Phone*: <input type="number" maxlength="10" name='PhoneN' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')"  size="16">

<form name='MyMail' onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">Your Email*: <input type="character" name='mailN' size="16">
```

Comment: Why do you need two forms? Why not just have 1 form with two fields?

Comment: I see the question is already answered, but I'm still curious what the problem was. I can't duplicate your problem with your original source. Ehm, you didn't nest form 2 inside form 1, did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this

```
<form name='MyForm' onsubmit="validatePhone();validateForm();" method="post">
  <label for="PhoneN">Phone*:</label>
  <input type="number" maxlength="10" name='PhoneN' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" size="16">
  <label for="mailN">Your Email*:</label>
  <input type="text" name='mailN' size="16">
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont really know what was the problem but u did.

Comment: Wrap all inputs in one form element and of course you can execute multiple functions on submit ;) I personaly for that purpose using jQuery + AJAX.

Comment: Yes, you can put as many inputs as you wish in one form element, and you don't need to holding your form action script on page, you can make external script than assign it to form action attribute.